# Создание поля состоящего из кнопок MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

В меню моей программы есть три MenuItem'а. Как используя mvvm сделать так чтобы при нажатии на любую из них строилось поле NxN, состоящее из кнопок, где N - определенное число,у каждого MenuItem'а оно свое. Нужны ли здесь модели или можно обойтись вьюмоделями? Хватит ли одной вьюмодели? я знаю что это можно сделать через RelayCommand, но как?

Comment: Передавайте `N` в качестве `CommandParameter`.

Comment: MenuItemы, кнопки - это все UI, вот и обрабатывайте из взаимодействие между собой во View

Comment: @Bulson можете подробнее все расписать?